# Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics

Tags: sql-server, heterogeneous, ansi-nulls

I have checked over the whole web and couldn't find a solution that seems to work for me..

I have recreated my stored procedure, making sure to have these lines as first lines:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE test_insert
AS
....
BEGIN
...
END
```

I only get this error when i call my stored procedure from php. it works fine in sql server..
i really don't know what else i can do..please help me ;_;

Comment: The key you seem to be missing: *for the connection*. You are setting options for the proc,  not the *connection*.

Comment: I cannot put a formal answer so :
@Andre Barber: You were right, adding it to the stored procedure did not work.

Here is what was needed to do:

In the PHP:
  

      $sql="EXEC my_store_procedure";
        $result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON") or die(mssql_get_last_message());
        $result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON") or die(mssql_get_last_message());
        $result= mssql_query($sql);

Answer (score 11):

Added this BEFORE your statement rather than at the start of the main query

```
$result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON;");
$result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example that works...
Try it like this

```
create procedure dbo.access_update @O_SQL_Error_State int = NULL     output

as

set ANSI_NULLS ON 

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON    

....
....

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not often a better answer is on another forum - but according to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d501b57-fc58-4fbe-9bec-6c38ad158a62/heterogeneous-queries-ansinulls-ansiwarnings?forum=sqldataaccess), the `SET` commands must be before the `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Tested and works with SQL Server 2017.

For example:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.access_update 
    @O_SQL_Error_State int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
    ...
```

Comment: This worked for me but you have to put GO after each line or you get 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. Thank you!