# Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS - Trigger dealing with linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, database-trigger, ansi-nulls

Upon trying to insert into table via app, I receive following error message.

> Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection.

Neither ANSI_NULLS ON nor ANSI_WARNINGS ON did help...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BenRef_UPDATE]
 ON [dbo].[ITRAEN]
  AFTER UPDATE
    AS

 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPDATE(poz2) 


   CREATE TABLE storeBenRef( 
      BeneficiaryRef VARCHAR(30),
      Partija VARCHAR(30) collate Serbian_Latin_100_CI_AS, 
      Datum DATETIME
     );

    INSERT INTO storeBenRef ( BeneficiaryRef, Partija, Datum ) 
      SELECT i.poz2, i.PARTIJA,i.DOTVORANJE
           FROM inserted i
             INNER JOIN deleted d 
                 ON i.PARTIJA = d.PARTIJA;


   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON


    UPDATE [EXPSRV1].[OPR].[protected].[TransferServiceArrangement] 
    SET PaymentDetailsBeneficiaryReferenceNumber = tmp.BeneficiaryRef
      FROM storeBenRef tmp
          INNER JOIN [EXPSRV1].[OPR].[protected].[TransferServiceArrangement]  
            trsa
              ON trsa.PaymentDetailsPayerAccountNumber = tmp.partija 
                   WHERE trsa.FirstPaymentDate = tmp.Datum



    DROP TABLE dbo.storeBenRef; 

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
     END;
```

Tried to put them before an update statement, tried to set them individually, 
but it did not work.

I ask for help.

Comment: You need to set these session variables before executing the procedure. How exactly are you connecting and executing the SP from your app?

Comment: There is no SP, insert into table is delegated directly from the source, this is just a trigger that will update another table located on the linked server, but I doubt this has anything to do with that one.

Comment: Hm maybe it has...
When I comment this UPDATE section there is no error.
You suggest I alter the SP responsible for transfering data from source to linked sarver table ?

Comment: If the linked server isn't SQL Server, the connection needs to set explicitly a value for those 2 behaviours. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818120/why-does-ansi-nulls-and-ansi-warnings-need-to-be-set-to-on-for-linked-server-que

Comment: It is sql server

Comment: I added nulls and warnings to sp's but nothing changed

Comment: What did you mean, where else should I add session variables ?

Comment: Is this not already answered either here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_and_msbi/2015/03/18/error-heterogeneous-queries-require-the-ansi_nulls-and-ansi_warnings-options-to-be-set-for-the-connection/   or    here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300322/heterogeneous-queries-require-the-ansi-nulls-and-ansi-warnings-options-to-be-set

Comment: Tried to put it before the statement, did not help...